# Python groupby with single line if else statement

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement, group-by, pandas-groupby

I would like to apply a single line if else statement to a group in my data frame, but unsure how to map it.

My data looks like this:

```
    user                in               out location  overlap    Time    overlap_new
0    ron  12/21/2021 10:11  12/21/2016 17:50     home     0  4:19:03      'complete'
1    ron  12/21/2016 13:26  12/21/2016 13:52   office     2  0:25:28      'complete'
2  april   12/21/2016 8:12  12/21/2016 17:27   office     0  8:15:03      'none'
3  april  12/21/2016 18:54  12/21/2016 22:56   office     0  4:02:36      'none'
4   andy   12/21/2016 8:57  12/21/2016 12:15     home     0  2:59:40      'partial'
5   andy   12/21/2016 8:57  12/21/2016 12:15     home     1  2:59:40      'partial'
```

I would like the overlap to be a single value as shown in overlap_new, based on the value in overlap.

Here is my code:

```
s = sample.groupby('user')['overlap']
sample.loc[:,'overlap_new'] = s.apply(['partial' if ele == 1 else 'complete' if ele ==2 else 'none' for ele in sample['overlap']])
```

How do I apply a groupby to a single if else line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with test values by [`Series.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.any.html) for match at least one value per groups:

```
f = lambda x: 'partial' if (x == 1).any() else 'complete' if (x == 2).any() else 'none'
sample['overlap_new'] = sample.groupby('user')['overlap'].transform(f)
print (sample)
    user                in               out location  overlap     Time  \
0    ron  12/21/2021 10:11  12/21/2016 17:50     home        0  4:19:03   
1    ron  12/21/2016 13:26  12/21/2016 13:52   office        2  0:25:28   
2  april   12/21/2016 8:12  12/21/2016 17:27   office        0  8:15:03   
3  april  12/21/2016 18:54  12/21/2016 22:56   office        0  4:02:36   
4   andy   12/21/2016 8:57  12/21/2016 12:15     home        0  2:59:40   
5   andy   12/21/2016 8:57  12/21/2016 12:15     home        1  2:59:40   

  overlap_new  
0    complete  
1    complete  
2        none  
3        none  
4     partial  
5     partial
```